# calculating a datetime difference for ISO 8601

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to handle some datetime values correctly. We have a SaaS provider that implements their API with a HTTP response code of 429 meaning that we have exceeded their rate, and to backoff. They pass a header in of "X-RateLimit-Reset" whose value is an ISO8601 date stamp of when our requests reset. I'm trying to take that value and then take Now and calculate how long I have to wait in seconds. So far I have built this code:

```
    elif ask.status_code == 429:
        print("API rate limit hit. Resting...")

        # ask.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'] is passed back with a ISO8601 time stamp of when the api limit will be reset.
        # example: “2016-12-13T18:38:00Z”
        a = time.strptime(ask.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        a = time.mktime(a)

        print(ask.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'])

        # I don't get this...
        myTZ = datetime.tzinfo
        myTZ.timezone.utc

        # Calculate the offset taking into account daylight saving time
        b = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=myTZ.timezone.utc).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
        b = time.strptime(b, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
        b = time.mktime(b)

        # Time in seconds to wait and retry
        apiReset = (b-a)+1

        print("Sleeping {} seconds".format(apiReset))
        time.sleep(apiReset)

        return self.CallAPI(uri, method, data, timeout)
```

and it just isn't doing what I need it to do.  I've widdled away a few exceptions but now I'm down to this one:

```
API rate limit hit. Resting...
2018-12-18T00:07:54Z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Development/evident.io/mainbody.py", line 22, in <module>
    EvidentIO.ListSubORGs()
  File "/Users/i864248/OneDrive - SAP         SE/Development/evident.io/evidentio.py", line 112, in ListSubORGs
    return self.APICallHandler('/api/v2/sub_organizations')
  File "/Users/i864248/OneDrive - SAP     SE/Development/evident.io/evidentio.py", line 297, in APICallHandler
    response = self.CallAPI(uri, method, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/i864248/OneDrive - SAP SE/Development/evident.io/evidentio.py", line 407, in CallAPI
    myTZ.timezone.utc
AttributeError: 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'timezone'
```

Can someone help me out on this? Maybe I'm not even doing it correctly from the get go?

Answer (score 0):

Ok of course shortly after posting this I found a decent solution.  Using some examples elsewhere I reduced the code to just this:

```
a = datetime.strptime(ask.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
timestamp = (a - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()

ts = time.time()
timeDiff = (timestamp - ts)

print("Sleeping for {} seconds".format(timeDiff))
time.sleep(timeDiff + 1) 
print("Continuing")
return self.CallAPI(uri, method, data, timeout)
```

And that seems to work pretty well.